# History API in html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

In history API, I can use `pushState()` for tabbing structure to display different content based  on tab clicked.

When ( click on tab2, the url changes to `http://localhost/mysite/tab2`

But When I bookmark this url and then open this bookmark, it shows this error:

> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost
>
> Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15

What workaround can be done to enable it for bookmarking?

PS: I have read about hashbang technnique but that is degrading trend now a days. So don't want to use hashbang.

Comment: So ... What error you get? Without any error or code it's impossible to give *any* meaningful advice... You should post *both* the error and code.

Comment: I am getting this error:
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15

Comment: In this question i am not asking for debug the error but asking for work around with usage of HTML5 history API to bookmark page....
So this question is not off the track

Comment: The question as it was, *was* very much off-topic as I had *no idea at all* what the problem might be. With the error you added, I have a pretty good idea what the problem is: namely, that your server-side code doesn't recognise the new URL.

Comment: Its not about the error what i got,Because when i manipulate url in browser through pushState function , that those urls will not exist in actual.So not able to bookmark.

But in hashbang something is done to make that url which does not exist in actual bookmarkable.

So my sole point of asking the question is whether bookmarking can be done using history api or not??

Comment: Yes, but this wasn't at all clear what your problem was in your original question, which was somewhat confusing, and didn't state the exact problem very clearly. This is probably because English isn't your first language (and this is fine), adding the error made it a lot clearer what your problem exactly is.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using Apache, you need to create an `.htaccess` file to redirect all requests to your first page (I assume `index.html`). That way, any incoming request to your server is routed to your `index.html` page, which you can then use to display the correct content based on the URL. This is how modern web framework routing works.